# Updating a list in drools then clause

Tags: java, drools

I have a rule where I need to call update/modify on every member of a list. Something like

```
when
    $students : ArrayList() from collect (Student (age > 20))
then
    # update all the students in $students list with category as Senior
    # call modify/update for every element of $students list
```

I can call a function and pass it *$students* list which will set the category on every member of the list.

Can someone please guide me how to call **update/modify** on every member of the list

Comment: Is that title correct?

Comment: @Carcigenicate : I chose a relevant title to the best of my understanding. I needed help regarding update funtion call on a list in the then clause of drools rule and the title (I guess) represents the same.

Kindly suggest a more relevant title. Happy to update :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a typo. It reads weird if you don't know what `drools` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule works but the second rule is preferred:

```
rule setcat-1
when
  $students : List() 
    from collect (Student (age > 20, cat != "senior"))
then
  for( int i = 0; i < $students.size(); ++i ){
    Student s = (Student)$students.get( i );
    modify( s ){ setCat( "senior" ) }
  }
end

rule setcat-2
when
  $student : Student (age > 20, cat != "senior")
then
  modify( $student ){ setCat( "senior" ) }
end
```

There is no reason for collecting all facts into a list so that you can iterate it. Drools does it just as well in the engine.